# Recursive __str__ property in Django class

Tags: python, django, recursion

I have this class with a self-referential foreign key in my Django models

```py
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('Category', blank=True, null=True)

    def cadena(self):
        if self.parent is None:
            return self.name
        else:
            return self.cadena(self.parent) + ' - ' + self.name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cadena()
```

I want to get a string with a parent of this Category with the method "cadena" like this:

```py
Cat - SubCat - SubSubCat
```

With this Code

```py
c = Category.objects.get(id=12)
print c.cadena()
```

And I get this error:

```py
TypeError: cadena() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

What is the problem? Why that error for 2 given params?

Comment: This line `return self.cadena` should be `return self.cadena()`

Comment: Typo, but same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To call the `cadena` method for the parent, you should call `self.parent.cadena()`. This will fix the `TypeError`.

```
def cadena(self):
    if self.parent is None:
        return self.name
    else:
        return self.parent.cadena() + ' - ' + self.name
```